# mesg return 'is y'

Tags: coreutils

Upon issuing 'mesg'

```
me@alpha:~$ mesg
 is y
```

The manual states

```
NAME
       mesg - display (or do not display) messages from other users
```

Does this means that someone hacked my machine and leave a message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is y` is the **allow**/disallow display messages argument of the mesg terminal program. If `mesg` returns `is y` it means that messages are allowed to be displayed. From `man mesg` :

```
NAME
       mesg - display (or do not display) messages from other users

ARGUMENTS
       n      Disallow messages.

       y      Allow messages to be displayed.

       If no arguments are given, mesg shows the current message status on
       standard error output.
```

Answer (score 1):

Also from the manpage:

```
y      Allow messages to be displayed.

If no arguments are given, mesg shows the  current  message  status  on
standard error output.
```

So all that means is that messages are allowed to be displayed.